# Контейнер для хранения данных

Tags: android, база-данных, xml, хранение-данных

Не знаю, какой контейнер выбрать для хранения данных.

Имеется перечень университетов, в каждом университете есть набор специальностей, для каждой специальности свой набор курсов, а в каждом курсе - перечень предметов.

Студент выбирает свой университет, специальность и курс, и это сохраняется в приложении. Потом он выбирает, какие предметы загрузить, а в каждом предмете есть набор ссылок на PDF-файлы. Пытался сделать через XML (которые загружаются с сервера), создал XML со списком университетов, для каждого университета XML со перечнем специальностей и номерами курсов, но как-то все не очень гибко получается. По сути мне нужно реализовать приложение под Android и сделать так, чтобы контейнер с данными в случае с расширения также работал. Т.е. сейчас это редактирование XML. Стоит ли для этого делать базу данных или можно как-нибудь обойтись простым способом для хранения этих данных?

Comment: покажите ваш xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно понял, какой же ответ хочет услышать автор.

Вам нужна древовидная вложенность с отношениями "один ко многим"? Она позволит делать, например, выборки "в каких университетах на каких специальностях одновременно изучают предметы X и Y, но не изучают предмет Z".

Для реализации хранения таких данных (и манипуляций с ними) прекрасно подходят базы данных, да. Делаете по таблице на каждую сущность и по дополнительной таблице-справочнику для реализации связей между сущностями. По желанию можно дополнительно заморочиться со внешними ключами (foreign keys) между таблицами, чтобы, например, исключить ссылки на несуществующие сущности.

Comment: Ну, вот так: Университет1 в нем Специальность1, в Специальность1 есть Курс1, Курс2, Курс3, в Курс1 есть Предмет1, Предмет2, в Предмет1 и Предмет2 несколько ссылок на PDF-файлы

Comment: такую структуру можно хранить в БД, да

Comment: Правильно ли я накидал структуру бд? http://i10.pixs.ru/storage/2/3/0/dbpng_7688234_19898230.png

Comment: @T2skler Ваш вариант не позволяет добавить один и тот же предмет в, например, разные университеты - у вас будет столько записей "математика", сколько раз математика встречается во всех университетах-специальностях-факультетах. если Вас это устраивает, то ок. но обычно сущности хранят (в 1 экземпляре) в одной таблице, а связи между ними - в другой.